# ADAL for java: Resolving dependencies for java client app sample

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

Are there any instructions available to run public-client-app-sample in ADAL for Java ? After building the sample jar and library jar files, an attempt to run "java -cp adal4j-0.1.0.jar;public-client-app-sample.jar PublicClient" yields (after entering the credentials)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/oauth2/s
dk/AuthorizationGrant.
What would be the appropriate classpath or is there a maven target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the code to include exec plugin in the sample. Simply use `mvn exec:java` to run the sample. I verified that it works

Comment: After entering credentials, I get this error message:  

[INFO] An exception occured while executing the Java class. null

"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.

Comment: Looks like you are using a web application client ID. You should be using the client id of your native (mobile/desktop) app.

Comment: Got it. I had registered the TestClient app as a web app indeed. After fixing the configuration in Azure, running the code worked as intended. Thanks.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if it helped you? It may serve other ADAL users as well.

Answer (score 0):

The 0.1.0 version of the adal4j maven library is unresolvable neither in com.microsoft.azure, nor in com.microsoft.aad. Here is the search result from maven central to confirm that:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22adal4j%22

When changing the adal4j to the latest available version (0.0.3) the following exception is produced:

`Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.openConnection(HttpHelper.java:110)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpGet(HttpHelper.java:43)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpGet(HttpHelper.java:38)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.MexParser.getWsTrustEndpointFromMexEndpoint(MexParser.java:87)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.processPasswordGrant(AuthenticationContext.java:747)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$000(AuthenticationContext.java:61)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:127)
    at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)`