# getting error while Databricks connection to Azure SQL DB with ActiveDirectoryPassword

Tags: jdbc, databricks, adal4j

I am trying to connect Azure sql db from Databricks with AAD - Password auth. I imported azure sql db& adal4j libs. but still getting below error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/AuthorizationGrant
```

stack trace:

```
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerADAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthToken(SQLServerADAL4JUtils.java:24)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:3609)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:3580)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:3548)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:261)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:103)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4290)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3157)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:82)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3121)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2026)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:569)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:5
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:590)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:474)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:548)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:380)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:327)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:215)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.AuthorizationGrant
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

imported nimbusds lib into my workspace.

here is config

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

    val config = Config(Map(

      "url"            -> "ServerName.database.windows.net",
      "databaseName"   -> "dbname",
      "dbTable"        -> "dbo.test",
      "user"           -> "alias@domain.com",
      "password"       -> "pwd",
      "authentication" -> "ActiveDirectoryPassword",
      "encrypt"        -> "true",
      "trustServerCertificate"->"false",
      "hostNameInCertificate"->"*.database.windows.net"
    ))

    val collection = spark.read.sqlDB(config)
    collection.show()
```

please help me if any one resolved this issue.

[image]

Comment: You are missing a library on your classpath (the one that contains the class `com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.AuthorizationGrant`)

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006441/integrating-azure-ad-into-a-java-web-application and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380910/adal-for-java-resolving-dependencies-for-java-client-app-sample, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457863/what-causes-and-what-are-the-differences-between-noclassdeffounderror-and-classn

Comment: thanks Mark for reply. I imported oauth2-oidc-sdk-3.0.jar into my workspace and attached to cluster. do I need to register it somewhere. uploaded snippet as well

Answer (score 1):

[Click here](https://github.com/tayganr/databricks/raw/master/Azure%20SQL%20DB%20with%20AAD%20Auth%20Setup.dbc) to download a working notebook.

### Create a Databricks Cluster

Known working configuration - Databricks Runtime 5.2 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11)

### Install the Spark Connector for Microsoft Azure SQL Database and SQL Server

1. Navigate to **Cluster > Library > Install New > Maven > Search Packages**
2. Switch to **Maven Central**
3. Search for **azure-sqldb-spark** (com.microsoft.azure:azure-sqldb-spark)
4. Click **Select**
5. Click **Install**

Known working version - com.microsoft.azure:azure-sqldb-spark:1.0.2

### Update Variables

Update variable values (custerName, server, database, table, username, password)

### Run the Initialisation command (ONCE ONLY)

This will do the following:

1. Create a folder called **init** under dbfs:/databricks/init/
2. Creta a sub-folder with the name of the Databricks cluster
3. Create a bash script per dependency

Bash Script Commands:
* wget: Retrieve content from a web server
* --quit: Turns off wget's output
*  -O: Output

Dependencies:

- http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/adal4j/1.6.0/adal4j-1.6.0.jar
- http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/5.24.1/oauth2-oidc-sdk-5.24.1.jar
- http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/minidev/json-smart/1.1.1/json-smart-1.1.1.jar
- http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/7.0.1/nimbus-jose-jwt-7.0.1.jar

### Restart the Databricks Cluster

This is needed to execute the init script.

### Run the last cell in this Notebook

This will test the ability to connect to an Azure SQL Database via Active Directory authentication.

**Init Command**

```scala
// Initialisation
// This code block only needs to be run once to create the init script for the cluster (file remains on restart)

// Get the cluster name
var clusterName = dbutils.widgets.get("cluster")

// Create dbfs:/databricks/init/ if it doesn’t exist.
dbutils.fs.mkdirs("dbfs:/databricks/init/")

// Create a directory named (clusterName) using Databricks File System - DBFS.
dbutils.fs.mkdirs(s"dbfs:/databricks/init/$clusterName/")

// Create the adal4j script.
dbutils.fs.put(s"/databricks/init/$clusterName/adal4j-install.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
wget --quiet -O /mnt/driver-daemon/jars/adal4j-1.6.0.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/adal4j/1.6.0/adal4j-1.6.0.jar
wget --quiet -O /mnt/jars/driver-daemon/adal4j-1.6.0.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/azure/adal4j/1.6.0/adal4j-1.6.0.jar""", true)

// Create the oauth2 script.
dbutils.fs.put(s"/databricks/init/$clusterName/oauth2-install.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
wget --quiet -O /mnt/driver-daemon/jars/oauth2-oidc-sdk-5.24.1.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/5.24.1/oauth2-oidc-sdk-5.24.1.jar
wget --quiet -O /mnt/jars/driver-daemon/oauth2-oidc-sdk-5.24.1.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/5.24.1/oauth2-oidc-sdk-5.24.1.jar""", true)

// Create the json script.
dbutils.fs.put(s"/databricks/init/$clusterName/json-smart-install.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
wget --quiet -O /mnt/driver-daemon/jars/json-smart-1.1.1.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/minidev/json-smart/1.1.1/json-smart-1.1.1.jar
wget --quiet -O /mnt/jars/driver-daemon/json-smart-1.1.1.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/net/minidev/json-smart/1.1.1/json-smart-1.1.1.jar""", true)

// Create the jwt script.
dbutils.fs.put(s"/databricks/init/$clusterName/jwt-install.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
wget --quiet -O /mnt/driver-daemon/jars/nimbus-jose-jwt-7.0.1.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/7.0.1/nimbus-jose-jwt-7.0.1.jar
wget --quiet -O /mnt/jars/driver-daemon/nimbus-jose-jwt-7.0.1.jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/7.0.1/nimbus-jose-jwt-7.0.1.jar""", true)

// Check that the cluster-specific init script exists.
display(dbutils.fs.ls(s"dbfs:/databricks/init/$clusterName/"))
```

**Test Command**

```scala
// Connect to Azure SQL Database via Active Directory Password Authentication
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

// Get Widget Values
var server = dbutils.widgets.get("server")
var database = dbutils.widgets.get("database")
var table = dbutils.widgets.get("table")
var username = dbutils.widgets.get("user")
var password = dbutils.widgets.get("password")

val config = Config(Map(
  "url"                    -> s"$server.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"           -> s"$database",
  "dbTable"                -> s"$table",
  "user"                   -> s"$username",
  "password"               -> s"$password",
  "authentication"         -> "ActiveDirectoryPassword",
  "encrypt"                -> "true",
  "ServerCertificate"      -> "false",
  "hostNameInCertificate"  -> "*.database.windows.net"
))

val collection = sqlContext.read.sqlDB(config)
collection.show()
```

Comment: I experienced that this is dependend on the Databricks Runtime. Everthing below Spark 3.0 is working, however the newer Runtimes are not working with it. Do you know what to update, so this would also work in the newer Runtimes of Databricks?

Answer (score 0):

As a 2020 update:

I did cluster init scripts as described, but in the end my working setup didn't seem to require that.

I ended up using scala 2.11 (note 2.11) and these libraries installed through UI: com.microsoft.azure:azure-sqldb-spark:1.0.2 and mssql_jdbc_8_2_2_jre8.jar (note jre8). Also I had to explicitly mention the driver class in config:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

val config = Config(Map(
   "url"            -> "....database.windows.net",
   "databaseName"   -> "...",
   "dbTable"        -> "...",
   "accessToken"           -> "...",
   "hostNameInCertificate" -> "*.database.windows.net",
   "encrypt"               -> "true",
   "ServerCertificate"      -> "false",
   "driver"                 -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
))

val collection = spark.read.sqlDB(config)
collection.show()
```

Token acquisition was done with msal (python):

```
import msal

TenantId = "...guid..."
authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TenantId
scope = "https://database.windows.net//.default"  # yes, with double "//"
ServicePrincipalId = "...guid..."
ServicePrincipalPwd = "secret"

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=ServicePrincipalId, authority=authority, client_credential=ServicePrincipalPwd, )

result = None
result = app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=[scope], account=None)

if not result:
    result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scope)

if "access_token" in result:
    sqlAzureAccessToken = result["access_token"]
```

Comment: Any scala version of token acquisition ?