# How can we connect Azure SQL database using Active Directory authentication in Azure databricks

Tags: active-directory, connection, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

How to put AAD session value instead on password and user name in the code shown here:

```
    import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
    import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

    val config = Config(Map(
      "url"            -> "kkk-server.database.windows.net:1433",
      "databaseName"   -> "MyDatabase",
      "dbTable"        -> "dbo.Clients",
      "user"           -> "AD-account",
      "password"       -> "xxxxxxxx",
      "connectTimeout" -> "5", //seconds
      "queryTimeout"   -> "5"  //seconds
    ))

    val collection = spark.read.sqlDB(config)
    collection.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Spark connector for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases-azure.html#connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-and-azure-sql-database-with-the-spark-connector) in Azure Databricks.

The Spark connector for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database also supports Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication. It allows you to securely connect to your Azure SQL databases from Azure Databricks using your AAD account. It provides interfaces that are similar to the built-in JDBC connector.

Here's the example:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

val config = Config(Map(
  "url"            -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"   -> "MyDatabase",
  "user"           -> "username ",
  "password"       -> "*********",
  "authentication" -> "ActiveDirectoryPassword",
  "encrypt"        -> "true"
))

val collection = sqlContext.read.SqlDB(config)
collection.show()
```

For more details, please see: [Connect Spark to Azure SQL Database using AAD authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector#connect-spark-to-azure-sql-database-using-aad-authentication)

Hope this helps.

Comment: But here we need to expose the password for my SSO login which is not feasible.

Comment: Maybe you can reference the answer of this blog: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790776/getting-error-while-databricks-connection-to-azure-sql-db-with-activedirectorypa

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication to connect to Azure SQL Database on Azure Databricks is not possible at this time. You should use SQL authentication.

If you try AAD authentication on Azure Databricks you may get error "This driver is not configured for integrated authentication" or similar error message.

Although it is possible to use AAD in Azure Data Lake.

Answer (score 0):

As the links provided by Leon Yue seem to be down this is the way to do it in Python that worked for me:

```
remote_table = (spark.read
  .format("sqlserver")
  .option("host", "<YOUR-HOST-HERE>")
  .option("user", "<YOUR-USERNAME-HERE>")
  .option("password", "<YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE>")
  .option("database", "<YOUR-DATABASE-HERE>")
  .option("dbtable", "<YOUR-SCHEMA-HERE>.<YOUR-TABLE-HERE>") # (if schema is not provided, it is defaulted to "dbo")
  .option("authentication", "ActiveDirectoryPassword")
  .load()
)
```