# How to connect to an Azure SQL Server using service principal in Scala

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, azure-active-directory

I am looking for a way to connect to an Azure Database using Service Principal **with SCALA**.

I want to be able to generate a token and use it in JDBC to connect to the database. Python example:

```
import adal

# Located in App Registrations from Azure Portal
tenant_id = "<< tenant id >> "

# Located in App Registrations from Azure Portal
resource_app_id_url = "https://database.windows.net/"

# Authority
authority = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenant_id

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_app_id_url, service_principal_id, service_principal_secret)
access_token = token["accessToken"]

jdbc_df = spark.read \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", dbtable) \
        .option("accessToken", access_token) \
        .option("encrypt", "true") \
        .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
        .load()
```

[Another SO Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52790776/getting-error-while-databricks-connection-to-azure-sql-db-with-activedirectorypa).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer after days of searching!

```
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


val AUTHORITY_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+tenant_id
val principalId = service_principal_id
val principalSecret = service_principal_secret
val URL="jdbc:sqlserver://xx.database.windows.net:1433;database=xx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30"



val service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
val context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY_URL, true, service);
val credential = new ClientCredential(principalId, principalSecret);
val result = context.acquireToken("https://database.windows.net/", credential, null).get();

// println("***********************")
// println(result.getAccessToken())
// println("***********************")


val df= spark.read 
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") 
        .option("url", URL) 
        .option("dbtable", "xx") 
        .option("accessToken", result.getAccessToken()) 
        .load()
```